# Return the page only when Future calculation is finished

Tags: scala, playframework

I have one controller in my application using Play Framework,

```
def controllerMethod() = Action{
  val someval = callToService()
  Ok(views.html.abc(someval))
}
```

`callToService` method in *service* class:

```
def callToService() : SomeRandomObject = {
  val somerandomobject = new SomeRandomObject()
  for(){
    call to webservice which returns future
    set the values in somerandomobject as per the response.
  }
  somerandomobject                      
}
```

When I am calling the webservice from within the for loop, lets say for 5 times, I set each time a property in `somerandomobject`. Because there is a webservice call in the for loop which returns a `Future[Response]`, the controller returns the page without even getting the value of `someval` and shows no data on page.

To prevent this, I have put the block in `await.result(future,timeout)` and have given some timeout. Which is very bad idea. What else I can do so that controller returns the page only after the `someval` object is available ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding the nature of how Play uses Futures.  The future doesn't need to complete by the time the function exits, because the function can itself return a future.

Let's say you have a function in your service that returns a Future containing a String:

```
def getSingleResult: Future[String]
```

To handle this in the controller, you can map the successful completion of the future to the resulting string.

```
def singleSource = Action.async {
  // send the string in the body of a 200 response
  getSingleResult.map(str => Ok(str))
}
```

Now, let's say you're calling a 5 web services and you want to handle the results at the same time in the controller.  (In this example, the `webServiceX` functions represent calls to web services; since these example functions return futures, we get the same effect.)

```
def webServiceCallA: Future[String] = // implementation
def webServiceCallB: Future[Int] = // implementation
def webServiceCallC: Future[Boolean] = // implementation
def webServiceCallD: Future[Foo] = // implementation
def webServiceCallE: Future[Bar] = // implementation
```

We can use a for-comprehension to complete these futures and construct an instance of SomeRandomClass to return the result.

```
case class SomeRandomClass(a: String, b: Int, c: Boolean, d: Foo, e: Bar)

def getUsingForComprehension: Future[SomeRandomObject] = {
    val eventualA = webServiceCallA
    val eventualB = webServiceCallB
    val eventualC = webServiceCallC
    val eventualD = webServiceCallD
    val eventualE = webServiceCallE
    for {
      a <- eventualA
      b <- eventualB
      c <- eventualC
      d <- eventualD
      e <- eventualE
    } yield SomeRandomClass(a, b, c, d, e)
  }
```

Note that `getUsingForComprehension` returns a `Future[SomeRandomClass]` even though we're not explicitly placing `SomeRandomClass(a, b, c, d, e)` in a future.  This is because - and **this is crucial** to your original question - we only create a SomeRandomClass when all the futures complete, and since we don't know when that will be, it has to happen in the future!

Back in the controller, we can use exactly the same approach as before to deal with the response.

```
def futuresAndMultipleSources = Action.async {
  // render your view, providing the result of the future
  getUsingForComprehension.map(someRandomObject => Ok(views.html.abc(someRandomObject)))
}
```

At no point do we block or explicitly wait for a future to complete!

Answer (score 4):

**Option 1:**

You could return future from callToService by composing future returned from web service. So callToService will have a return type of `Future[SomeRandomObject]` and change `def some` to,

```
def some = Action.async {
    import scala.util._
    callToService().onComplete {
      case Success(s) =>Ok(views.html.abc(s))
      case Failure(e) => BadRequest
   }
}
```

**Option 2:**

Use `Await.result` on the returned future from webservice and the rest of the code will remain unchanged. But this option is blocking